# PHP comparing two POST not working

Tags: php

I'm currently having an issue with PHP, I'm trying to compare two POST variables using an if statement. However when i use != it will not work, but == will work and i don't understand why.

```
if($_POST["PasswordSignUp"] != $_POST[PasswordSignUpRepeat]){
setcookie("PassMatch","Error");
}
```

Edit:
Okay, i just had an idea that may fix my problem, at the moment i am using the cookie as basically a global variable. Is there a way to define a global variable to use from page to page without having to 'include' or 'require' it into the code.

Comment: you need quotes around the second index.

Comment: What are the values? Do they not equal each other? Are those the correct `name`s of your input fields? Is it a `POST` request?

Comment: @Timbob1232, you don't mark questions as answered. Read here :- http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST[PasswordSignUpRepeat]` should be `$_POST['PasswordSignUpRepeat']`. Also, use paranthesis in comparison. It isn't mandatory, but it's a good process to follow.

```
if(($_POST["PasswordSignUp"]) != ($_POST['PasswordSignUpRepeat'])){
setcookie("PassMatch","Error");
}
```

Comment: -1; this is wrong. Assuming that `PasswordSignUpRepeat` hasn't been defined as a constant, the expressions `$_POST[PasswordSignUpRepeat]` and `$_POST['PasswordSignUpRepeat']` evaluate to the same thing (although the former throws a warning). There's no way that adding the quotes in can have solved the OP's problem. On a subjective side note, I find your gratuitous use of extra parentheses here ugly and unhelpful and would advise against it.

Comment: @MarkAmery
How would you pass a `constant` variable as a POST? If he were to use that variable as a constant, he could directly do `$_POST["PasswordSignUp"] != PasswordSignUpRepeat` and not use $_POST[constant name].
On the sarcastic side note, I find your comment really un-needed and your downvote pretty stupid.

Answer (score -1):

Try below:-

```
if($_POST['PasswordSignUp'] !== $_POST['PasswordSignUpRepeat']){
setcookie("PassMatch","Error");
}
```

!== will check fr value and type.